# How can I do the kotlin mediaPlayer shuffle play

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create shuffle mode for the music-player application. The problem is; The sound on my list only plays once and stops when finished. but I want all the sounds on my list to be shuffled and played automatically. I am very new to Android programming, I tried hard but failed. I also tried the setOnCompletionListener {} method but it didn't work. I need help. thanks everyone

here are my sample codes;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val Sound1 = R.raw.sound01
        val Sound2 = R.raw.sound02
        val Sound3 = R.raw.sound03
        val Sound4 = R.raw.sound04
        val Sound5 = R.raw.sound05

        val soundList = ArrayList<Int>()
        soundList.add(Sound1)
        soundList.add(Sound2)
        soundList.add(Sound3)
        soundList.add(Sound4)
        soundList.add(Sound5)

        shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val randomList = Random.nextInt(soundList.size)
            val sound = soundList.get(randomList)
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound)
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a completion listener that releases the original player and creates a new one.

If you want to play shuffled, you need a variable to store the shuffled list and remove tracks as you play them so you know when to reshuffle. The way you're picking random sounds, you could play the same sound twice in a row sometimes.

By the way, you can create your list more concisely.

I didn't test this code. Sorry for any errors.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val sounds = listOf(
        R.raw.sound01,
        R.raw.sound02,
        R.raw.sound03,
        R.raw.sound04,
        R.raw.sound05
    )
    
    var shuffledSounds = sounds.shuffled()

    fun newTrack() {
        if (shuffledSounds.isEmpty()) {
            shuffledSounds = sounds.shuffled()
        }
        val nextSound = shuffledSounds.first()
        shuffledSounds = shuffledSounds - nextSound
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, nextSound).apply {
            setOnCompletionListener{
                it.release()
                newTrack()
            }
            start()
        }
    }

    shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener {
        newTrack()
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. These codes work perfectly.
Thanks a lot again